# Validating JSON object in If controller - JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to performance testing. I am trying a script and want to know the expression on how to validate if a JSON object is present in response or not.

consider two samplers. In first sampler response I am receiving a JSON object. Sometimes it will be empty and sometimes it might have single or multiple objects. Now I want to check if response is there or not. If response is there I want to run second sampler, else not. Is there any expression to check just if response is there or not while ignoring its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) which provides possibility to execute arbitrary [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries against the response (or a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)) and save the evaluation results into another JMeter Variable.

So you can read this variable generated by the JSON Extractor in the If Controller and if the variable value is `true` - they you can just put its reference name `${like this}` into the If Controller's condition area.

If your logic is more complex you can use [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) functions, If Controller will run its child(ren) if the expression or variable returns `true`

Comment: Thanks. But variable value here is not Boolean. it is alpha numeric characters that is generated randomly. so  can i use anything like ${Variable} != null ?

Comment: As far as I know JSON Extractor still creates a Variable even if there wasn't a match so I think you need to go for [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like `${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(vars.get('Variable')),)}`